# canvas - Draw a line and move it with the mouse

Tags: canvas

Hello everyone I want to get an example of how to move a drawn canvas line with the mouse and, after shifting the mouse, get its new coordinates, even in console.log

code:

```
<canvas id="graph" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
   ctx.lineTo(150, 100);
   ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

Please help me!
I'm a beginner and I'm trying to figure out how it works. I need an example! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to upset you newbie, but writing dragging from scratch may seem to you not an easy task, writing on pure java script requires you to implement it yourself, if you don't want to write it yourself better use a library for canvas where it is implemented, for example fabric js

Here is the code that shows dragging lines for canvas without zooming and world offset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        // Coordinates of the start and end points of the line
        var startX = 50;
        var startY = 50;
        var endX = 250;
        var endY = 250;

        function renderLine() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
            ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        window.onresize = function() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            renderLine();
        }

        var dragging = false;
        var draggOffsetX = 0;
        var draggOffsetY = 0;

        function hitTestLine(mouseX, mouseY) {
            var tolerance = 5;

            // Check if the mouse click is within the line's bounding box
            if (mouseX >= Math.min(startX, endX) && mouseX <= Math.max(startX, endX) &&
                mouseY >= Math.min(startY, endY) && mouseY <= Math.max(startY, endY)) 
            {
                // Calculate the distance between the mouse click and the line using the cross product
                const distance = Math.abs((endX - startX) * (startY - mouseY) - (startX - mouseX) * (endY - startY)) /
                     Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endX - startX, 2) + Math.pow(endY - startY, 2));

                // Check if the distance is within the tolerance range
                if (distance <= tolerance) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
            var mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            if (hitTestLine(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                dragging = true;
                draggOffsetX = mouseX;
                draggOffsetY = mouseY;
            }
            else
                dragging = false;

        });

        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
            dragging = false;
            console.log("new coords: {\n",
                `startX: ${startX}\n`,
                `startY: ${startY}\n`,
                `endX: ${endX}\n`,
                `endY: ${endY}\n`,
            "}");
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            var mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            if (dragging) {
                // Calculate the new position of the line
                let deltaX = mouseX - draggOffsetX;
                let deltaY = mouseY - draggOffsetY; 
                startX += deltaX;
                startY += deltaY;
                endX += deltaX;
                endY += deltaY;
                draggOffsetX = mouseX;
                draggOffsetY = mouseY;
                canvas.style.cursor = "grabbing";
            }

            else {
                if (hitTestLine(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                    //console.log('mouse is on the line');
                    canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
                } else {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                    //console.log('mouse is not on the line');
                    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
                }
            }
            renderLine();
        });

        renderLine();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```